# Particles in Box2d and libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d, particle-system, particles

Sorry for such a generic question, but I just wanted to ask if there is an effective way to integrate particle effect using Box2d physics engine in libgdx. Basically I want to integrate a blood splatter effect between two bodies with realistic physics based particles. I cannot find any good tutorials to do so and would love suggestions.

I would like to integrate this in libgdx. Liquidfun seems to be good, but I have heard it gives problems with portability and doesn't work well with desktop applications. Particle effects in libgdx as per my understanding doesn't follow the physiscs involved with particles, so I don't think I should go that way either.

Answer (score 1):

Liquidfun is an extension of box2D, it has additional functionality to create particle groups that behaves like liquids.

You need to integrate Google's [liquidfun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) with libgdx.

---

You should try [gdx-liquidfun-extension](https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension), An extension to implement liquidfun into libgdx.

Inject [dependency](https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension/wiki/Setup) in your project, refresh/sync gradle and build.